# Nodejs and Sqlite. Perform long queries

Tags: node.js, performance, sqlite, execution

I have to perform 2 queries: query A is long (20 seconds) and query B is fast (1 second).
I want to guarantee that query B is performed fast also if query A is running.
How can i achive this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

It may not be easy to do because of how SQLite does locking.

From official [Appropriate Uses For SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html) documentation:

> SQLite supports an unlimited number of simultaneous readers, but it will only allow one writer at any instant in time. For many situations, this is not a problem. Writer queue up. Each application does its database work quickly and moves on, and no lock lasts for more than a few dozen milliseconds. But there are some applications that require more concurrency, and those applications may need to seek a different solution.
>   [...]
>   SQLite only supports one writer at a time per database file. But in most cases, a write transaction only takes milliseconds and so multiple writers can simply take turns. SQLite will handle more write concurrency that many people suspect. Nevertheless, client/server database systems, because they have a long-running server process at hand to coordinate access, can usually handle far more write concurrency than SQLite ever will.

It may not be the best way to use SQLite, as the SQLite documentation states, when you have so many data that a single query takes so long.

There is no easy solution to fix that, other than using a real RDBMS like PostgreSQL.

And since you didn't include those queries that take so long it's also impossible to tell you anything more than that. Of course maybe your queries could be optimized but we don't know that.

Comment: Queries are a simple select * from table and the table has 10000000 records (for example).